# Unable to start the Phusion Passenger logging agent: it seems to have been killed with signal SIGKILL during startup

Tags: apache, passenger, rack, phusion

While starting Passenger with apache, I am getting the following error:

```
[ 2014-09-29 08:35:08.7694 18178/7f4ed722d700 apache2/Hooks.cpp:1303 ]: Initializing Phusion Passenger...
[ 2014-09-29 08:35:08.7806 18179/7fc2336a7720 agents/Base.cpp:1591 ]: Random seed: 1411994108
[ 2014-09-29 08:35:08.7807 18179/7fc2336a7720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:698 ]: Starting Watchdog...
[ 2014-09-29 08:35:08.7809 18179/7fc2336a7720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:538 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'puppet', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'puppet', 'log_level' => '3', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.52', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.52', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'prestart_urls' => 'aHR0cHM6Ly9kZXYtcHVwcGV0Y2EuYm55bWVsbG9uLm5ldC91c3Ivc2hhcmUvcHVwcGV0L3JhY2svcHVwcGV0bWFzdGVyZC9wdWJsaWMA', 'temp_dir' => '/var/log/httpd', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.52', 'web_server_pid' => '18178', 'web_server_type' => 'apache', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '2', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '2' }
[ 2014-09-29 08:35:08.8074 18182/7ff9c2f6b720 agents/Base.cpp:1591 ]: Random seed: 1411994108
[ 2014-09-29 08:35:08.8076 18182/7ff9c2f6b720 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:643 ]: Starting PassengerHelperAgent...
[ 2014-09-29 08:35:08.8156 18182/7ff9c2f6b720 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:650 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/var/log/httpd/passenger.1.0.18178/generation-0/request
[ 2014-09-29 08:35:08.8308 18187/7f4b9962c7e0 agents/Base.cpp:1591 ]: Random seed: 1411994108
[ 2014-09-29 08:35:08.8312 18187/7f4b9962c7e0 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:333 ]: Starting PassengerLoggingAgent...
**[Mon Sep 29 08:35:09.859284 2014] [passenger:error] [pid 18178:tid 139976593561344] *** Passenger could not be initialized because of this error: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because it encountered the following error during startup: **Unable to start the Phusion Passenger logging agent: it seems to have been killed with signal SIGKILL during startup****
```

I could find the PassengerLoggingAgent in this location:
`./usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.52/buildout/agents/PassengerLoggingAgent`

I did a Gem install of Passenger and the build ran fine.

Environment:
RHEL 6.4
Passenger Version: 4.0.52
Apache: 2.4.2

```html
httpd.conf:
 LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.52/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.52
     PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby
     PassengerLogLevel 3
     PassengerUser puppet
     PassengerGroup puppet
     PassengerDefaultUser puppet
     PassengerDefaultGroup puppet
     PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on
     PassengerTempDir /var/log/httpd
     PassengerSpawnMethod direct
     PassengerStartTimeout 500
     PassengerPreStart https://myserver.com/usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd/public
   </IfModule>

conf.d
PassengerMaxPoolSize 12
# Recycle master processes after they service 1000 requests
PassengerMaxRequests 1000
# Stop processes if they sit idle for 10 minutes
PassengerPoolIdleTime 600

Listen 8140
<VirtualHost *:8140>
    # Make Apache hand off HTTP requests to Puppet earlier, at the cost of
    # interfering with mod_proxy, mod_rewrite, etc. See note below.
    PassengerHighPerformance On

    ServerName myserver.com

    SSLEngine On

    # Only allow high security cryptography. Alter if needed for compatibility.
    SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!IDEA:!ECDSA:kEDH:CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA
    SSLHonorCipherOrder     on

    SSLCertificateFile      /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/myserver.com.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/myserver.com.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crt.pem
    SSLCACertificateFile    /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crt.pem
    SSLCARevocationFile     /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crl.pem
    SSLCARevocationCheck        chain
    SSLVerifyClient         optional
    SSLVerifyDepth          1
    SSLOptions              +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData

    # Apache 2.4 introduces the SSLCARevocationCheck directive and sets it to none
        # which effectively disables CRL checking. If you are using Apache 2.4+ you must
    # specify 'SSLCARevocationCheck chain' to actually use the CRL.

    # These request headers are used to pass the client certificate
    # authentication information on to the puppet master process
    RequestHeader set X-SSL-Subject %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}e
    RequestHeader set X-Client-DN %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}e
    RequestHeader set X-Client-Verify %{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY}e

    DocumentRoot /usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd/public
    PassengerAppRoot /usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd

    <Directory /usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd/>
      Options None
      AllowOverride all
      # Apply the right behavior depending on Apache version.
      <IfVersion < 2.4>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
      </IfVersion>
      <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all granted
      </IfVersion>
      Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd/public >
      Options None
      AllowOverride all
      # Apply the right behavior depending on Apache version.
      <IfVersion < 2.4>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
      </IfVersion>
      <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all granted
      </IfVersion>
      Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/myserver.com_ssl_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/myserver.com_ssl_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Can someone please help to resolve this?

Comment: enough RAM available?

Comment: yes. have 6GB free mem

Answer (score 0):

started the server with at now command prompt. and it worked. Thanks for help!